# php include() not working

Tags: php, include, database-connection

I'm making a simple program to interact with a database.  I have taken a username variable from the user in a file called "connect_database.php" and called it $un.  I then try to access that variable in another file where I have to submit the username to a database with a query.  Every variable in the query has gone through except the username so I concluded it was due to my use of the include().  Any help?

```
include ("connect_database.php");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `my_proj`. `inci` (
    `type`, `date`, `time`, `reporter`, `ID`, `desc`)
    VALUES ('$typeinc', CURDATE(), CURTIME(), '$un' ,NULL, '$text');"
) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: where is the connect_database.php? where is this script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to re-read the documentation on `include` and its brothers. They don't behave like you'd expect; instead of resolving the include path relative to the current file (the one you're looking at), they use the current working directory and the include path, which can be anything, depending on the OS, the web server, the PHP configuration files, and anything that has been executed before the include happens. Using `require` instead of `include`, like others have suggested, will not solve your problem, but it will tell you whether the include did infact fail.

You can solve your include problem through two means: Either control the current working directory and the include path and apply code discipline to make sure they don't change; or use absolute includes - the `__FILE__` constant combined with `dirname` can be used to emulate the behavior which should have been the default.

On side note, the way you concatenate strings into queries is an SQL injection attack waiting to happen. You better step away from the mysql_XXXX() API now and use something that supports parametrized queries (PDO is great, mysqli also works).

Answer (score 2):

I would change the `include()` to a `require()`, since your program doesn't work without it. They are the same, however `require` will kill the execution if the file can't be included.

Then, once you're sure that the file is actually be included, double-check that the value is being set properly:

```
require("connect_database.php");
var_dump($un);
```

If that doesn't work, go back to the `connect_database.php` file and check your spelling.

Answer (score 1):

```
require_once("connect_database.php");
```

Should fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

replace the `include()` with `require_once()`, look at the apache error log, it will show you the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Where is `$un` declared?  Globally or in a function?  Is the query you are using where it does not show up in a function?  If so the variable is not accessible from there.  See [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Maybe you need `global $un;` somewhere or assign $un to `$GLOBALS['un']` and reference it that way.